# In Jira how do I configure what actions are available for a ticket in the sprint view?

Tags: configuration, jira

In the SCRUM planning screen there is a "Details View" on the left.

How do I configure this to show only the things I am interested in, and hide those I am not. Also there are things I am occasionally interested in that I would like to shuffle to the bottom (like attachments).

Is there a bluffers guide to Jira configuration? The atlassian help pages are... not helping me...

Edit:
Sorry I was not clear enough.

I want to hide things like Fix Versions and Dates and  re-order things like People to be lower on the list of things. Not alter what tickets I see.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see what you are interested in, you can create quick filters in the following manner:

- Click on Board -> Configure.
- Go to "Quick Filters"
- Configure and add a new filter

Comment: That lets me alter what tickets I see, not the things that I can do to a selected ticket (right?!)

Comment: A screenshot would be useful to help us understand your problem :)